# WPF Usercontrol, Hosting dynamic content for reuse of UserControl. MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'll try to be very clear of what I'm trying to accomplish and am open to suggestions on other ways to achieve my desired result.

The 1000 foot view.

I have a `UserControl` that I want to reuse in every screen in my application. This control is more of a template look and feel with an icon (`bindable`), dynamic (`bindable`) label.

**UserControl.xaml** (CardView.xaml)

```
<Border BorderBrush="{Binding Path=BorderColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
     <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Style="{StaticResource CardStyle}">
      <StackPanel>
           <Border Style="{StaticResource MyBorderStyle}">
               <Label Content="{Binding Path=CardTitle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
            </Border>
      </StackPanel>
      <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelIcon}">
          <Path Fill="#FF000000" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
             Stretch="UniformToFill"  Data="{Binding Path=VectorString, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      // Dynamic Content Here. 
      //   Any kind of XAML content for the consumer of the control. 
      //     not in C# but I want to host the control and put controls in 
      //     here that I can bind to in XMAL by parents view model. 
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

**Consumer code** (customer.xaml)

```
<local:CardView CardTitle="Test" VectorString="F1 M" BorderColor="#FF0088">
  // Here's where I want to put dynamic XAML content.
  // Want to host anything and bind to it using the consumers View Model.
  // Example
     <Button Content="{Binding SomeText}" />
     <StackPanel>
         <Button>..... variable content but bindable
     </StackPanel>
 </local:CardView>
```

So in summary I have a user control that I want to to use in multiple places and have variable content in the body. The variable content will be marked up in the consumer XAML.

Some suggestions I've dug up searching, but doesn't seem to fit the model

1. Use a content template. I was going to but how do you bind to controls in a content template?
2. Content presenter. How do I bind to consumers view model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy doable by using a `ContentControl`. Just insert it into your CardView.xaml:

```
<Border BorderBrush="{Binding Path=BorderColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Style="{StaticResource CardStyle}">
  <StackPanel>
       <Border Style="{StaticResource MyBorderStyle}">
           <Label Content="{Binding Path=CardTitle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
        </Border>
  </StackPanel>
  <Label Style="{StaticResource LabelIcon}">
      <Path Fill="#FF000000" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
         Stretch="UniformToFill"  Data="{Binding Path=VectorString, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  // Dynamic Content Here. 
  <ContentControl Content={Binding CustomContent} /> 
</StackPanel>
```

And then in your ViewModel add a property 'CustomContent' of type object which contains an instance of your `Customer`.

Comment: I put this in my code but it doesn't work. When you say "in your ViewModel add a property 'Custom Content' do you mean in the CardView.cs file registering a dependency property or in the CardViewViewModel.cs file? tried to put a button in the XMAL markup but the entire content of the local:CardView is now only a button and I can only have one button

Comment: I need to be able to do this in the consumer code                                <local:Cardview><Button /><Button/><Label /><Label /><TextBox /></local:CardView>. Put any content in the markup. With the code you showed me I can't do that unless i'm missing fundamental.

Comment: I hope I can clarify this. In the CardView.xaml you add the Content is binding to the CustomContent property in your CardViewViewmodel.cs. Then you put a instance of  your Customer into the CustomContent property. If you now want to switch to another screen of your application, you put an instance of that screen in the CustomContent property.